# is there any way to configure gradle to check spelling in strings.xml?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, lint

I'd like `strings.xml` to be checked for spelling while building with gradle. Since we use continuous integration we need it to be configured for building from command-line not just in Android Studio. Any way to do it?

PS. I've tried:

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false

    // check *only* the given issue id's
    check 'Typos'
}
```

strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Project</string>

    <!-- Common Words -->
    <string name="test_spelling">sdfsdfdfds</string>
```

and

> ./gradlew assembleDebug lint

but got nothing:

```
:app:lint
Ran lint on variant release: 0 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 0 issues found
Wrote HTML report to     file:/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/Project/app/build/outputs/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/Project/app/build/outputs/lint-results.xml
```

Also i've checked `lint --show` :

```
...

Typos
-----
Summary: Spelling error

Priority: 7 / 10
Severity: Warning
Category: Correctness:Messages

This check looks through the string definitions, and if it finds any words
that look like likely misspellings, they are flagged.

...
```

PPS. If i add another rule to check (`check 'Typos', 'TypographyEllipsis'`) i'm getting warnings (for `TypographyEllipsis`) as expected, so in general linting works. For some reason "Typos" rule is not working only

Comment: just a thought, maybe Lint does that, so you may want to -somehow- include a call to lint within your build.gradle? not sure if doable or possible, just a hint :)

Comment: event ```checkAllWarnings true``` doesent seem to pick this up. weird...

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on something similar, so have not completed my work.  Not sure if you have an answer as yet, as it was asked a while ago.  Here is what I have.

The code you have here:

```
lintOptions {
abortOnError false

// check *only* the given issue id's
check 'Typos'
}
```

should be fine.  You can also add it within a flavor, to be more restrictive, if you are using them.

To get the report from the command line, you need to execute:

```
./gradlew lintAssembleDebug
```

or whatever your flavor is, e.g. `./gradlew lintAssembleMyFlavorDebug`

I am trying to make use of the `lintOptions.check()` method, to programmatically add the checks I want, but no luck yet.  Another alternative is as described [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/continuous-linting/) by Jason Atwood.  I am looking at this, adding the blank file:

```
ext.lintCheckList = [
    // Blank default list
] as String[]
```

to the repo, and replacing that in the CI job, as needed.

Hope that helps.

**Update:**

The command is incorrect.  It should be

```
./gradlew lintDebug
```

or

```
./gradlew lintMyFlavorDebug
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

If you do want spell check feature that is enabled by default in Android Studio IDE then follow the below given steps,

1. Go to Android Studio -> Preferences on your Mac OS X (Should be Window -> Preferences on Windows OS)
2. Now look for Inspections (if you cant trace it just use the Search)
3. Now look for the Spellings check box and check it (this also checks the Typo)
4. Apply and Close

Thats it!! You would now see any Typo or spelling correction highlights in Android Studio.

[image: Settings]